# event className not working

Tags: css, json, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar from arshaw.com/fullcalendar for displaying events on a corporate intranet calendar. I had the className attribute working, made a couple changes to some code and now cannot figure out why it's not working. Here is the json that is returned from my service

```
[
    {
        "allDay":true,
        "className":"corporate",
        "editable":null,
        "end":null,
        "id":null,
        "start":"2010-07-05T00:00:00.0000000",
        "title":"4th of July Holiday (Day Off)",
        "url":"\/en\/EmployeeResources\/Calendar\/Corporate\/2010\/07\/4th_of_july_holiday.aspx"
    }
]
```

everything works fine, except for assigning the 'corporate' className to the event items on the calendar.

This is the code that I'm using on document.ready to load the calendar events, which again, works fine, it's just the className's that I'm having trouble with

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', '/layouts/calendar/SitecoreCalendarEventsHandler.ashx?calendar=Corporate')
```

I'll also note, I'm using the latest version from arshaw.com (1.4.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind, it seems that it was being generated, web developer toolbar was not showing the class being added, but when I viewed generated source, that showed the class name. I had some messed up CSS, which was why the style appeared to not be showing up